# anyway to add css3 transition animation to element on jQuery event

Tags: jquery, animation, css, transition

is there a way to add a css3 animation upon a jQuery event for example:

```
<style>
.box{
width:100px;
height:100px;
bakground-color:#000;
}

.animate{
 width:0px;
 -webkit-transition-property: width; -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
 -moz-transition-property: width; -moz-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

<style>

<html>
<div class="box"></div>

<button>click me to animate</button>

$('button').click(function(){
$('.box').addClass('animate');
});

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the

```
 -webkit-transition-property: width; -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
     -moz-transition-property: width; -moz-transition-duration: 500ms;
```

in the .box declaration.
Your JS is fine.

Comment: that isn't working for me, nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: it works in a fiddle, but i am trying to get it to work. looks like i just am missing something in my actual code. thank!

Answer (score 1):

I think animo.js could be your answer http://labs.bigroomstudios.com/libraries/animo-js (via http://tympanus.net/codrops/collective/collective-80/)

Per their site...

> "You can easily stack animations to fire one after another, specify callbacks for the completion of an animation, or simply fire animations on any event or at any moment you please."