# perform CSS3 animation after using jQuery .appendTo

Tags: jquery, css

I want to use `.appendTo()` to modify the DOM position of an element. Once this is complete I need to animate the element with CSS3.

The element will not animate, instead it snaps to the new CSS style.

JavaScript:

```
$(".run").click(function() {
    $(".imageOriginal").appendTo(".insert").toggleClass("imageAnimated");   
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="insert"> </div>
<img src="img/img1.png" class="imageOriginal"/>
```

CSS:

```
.imageOriginal {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
}
.imageAnimated {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

I separated the the `.appendTo()` and the `.toggleClass()` methods to fire on two different click events. This method works (but obviously isn't desired). I also tried using `.delay(1000)` after the append, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: JQuery UI provides the .switchClass() function as described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248542/jquery-animate-with-css-class-only-without-explicit-styles

Comment: @Stephen Have they updated jQuery UI to use CSS3 transitions?

Comment: @Stephen Please don't recommend an entire (bloated, rubbish) library just for a single function that implements easily hand-codable behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps this thread could help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589104/anyway-to-add-css3-transition-animation-to-element-on-jquery-event

Comment: I would like to avoid jquery UI ;)

Comment: @Stefan sadly that method does not work (i attempted it, and the same result was achieved (no animation))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are appending the content and then toggling the class at the same time. If you remove the `.appendTo()` call it works fine:

```
$(".imageOriginal").toggleClass("imageAnimated");
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/38FrD/1/

I'm not really sure what is happening but if you watch the image element in FireBug you can see that the `transition` property that gets added has a duration of `0s` even though a duration was specified.

Also `.delay()` only works for queues (like `.animate()` calls).

**UPDATE**

If you place the `.toggleClass()` call inside a `setTimeout` anonymous function then it appears to work as desired:

```
$(".run").click(function() {
    var $this = $(".imageOriginal");
    $this.appendTo('.insert');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.toggleClass("imageAnimated");
    }, 0);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/38FrD/2/

Comment: Thanks I was under the impression .delay() would delay whatever method occured after the call. Still not sure how to fix this- the last resort would be to use jquery .animate instead of CSS3

Comment: @porfuse Just curious, why are you appending the image to another element? Also I updated my answer with a solution that should work for you.

Comment: I want to animate a group of images inside a wrapper, **except** the one that was clicked has a different animation- so I'll be using $(this) eventually. I'm appending the clicked image to another div so I can target it and give that particular image a differing animation.

Comment: @porfuse Did you see the **update** to my answer? Setting a timeout seems to do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I'll have to use that (even if its a little sloppy). I attempted doing .append().css({ my animations }) but it had no effect.