# Trigger CSS transition on appended element

Tags: javascript, css, dom

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595143/perform-css3-animation-after-using-jquery-appendto) observes, immediate CSS transitions on newly-appended elements are somehow ignored - the end state of the transition is rendered immediately.

For example, given this CSS (prefixes omitted here):

```
.box { 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box.in { opacity: 1; }
```

The opacity of this element will be set immediately to 1:

```
// Does not animate
var $a = $('<div>')
    .addClass('box a')
    .appendTo('#wrapper');
$a.addClass('in');
```

I have seen several ways of triggering the transition to get the expected behaviour:

```
// Does animate
var $b = $('<div>')
    .addClass('box b')
    .appendTo('#wrapper');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.b').addClass('in');
},0);

// Does animate
var $c = $('<div>')
    .addClass('box c')
    .appendTo('#wrapper');

$c[0]. offsetWidth = $c[0].offsetWidth
$c.addClass('in');

// Does animate
var $d = $('<div>')
    .addClass('box d')
    .appendTo('#wrapper');
$d.focus().addClass('in');
```

The same methods apply to vanilla JS DOM manipulation - this is not jQuery-specific behaviour.

Edit - I am using Chrome 35.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/q34kA/) (includes vanilla JS example).

- Why are immediate CSS animations on appended elements ignored?
- How and why do these methods work?
- Are there other ways of doing it
- **Which, if any, is the preferred solution?**

Comment: Good question, it's possible the animation is imminent due to the scripting engine optimizing your code.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The cause of not animating the newly added element is batching reflows by browsers.

When element is added, reflow is needed. The same applies to adding the class. However when you do both in **single javascript round**, browser takes its chance to optimize out the first one. In that case, there is only single (initial and final at the same time) style value, so no transition is going to happen.

The `setTimeout` trick works, because it delays the class addition to another javascript round, so there are two values present to the rendering engine, that needs to be calculated, as there is point in time, when the first one is presented to the user.

There is another exception of the batching rule. Browser need to calculate the immediate value, if you are trying to access it. One of these values is `offsetWidth`. When you are accessing it, the reflow is triggered. Another one is done separately during the actual display. Again, we have two different style values, so we can interpolate them in time.

This is really one of very few occasion, when this behaviour is desirable. Most of the time accessing the reflow-causing properties in between DOM modifications can cause serious slowdown.

The preferred solution may vary from person to person, but for me, the access of `offsetWidth` (or `getComputedStyle()`) is the best. There are cases, when `setTimeout` is fired without styles recalculation in between. This is rare case, mostly on loaded sites, but it happens. Then you won't get your animation. By accessing any calculated style, you are forcing the browser to actually calculate it.

Comment: *"The setTimeout trick works, because it delays the class addition to another javascript round"* Note that on Firefox, the `setTimeout` duration matters. I don't know the details, but for me (Firefox 42, Linux), 3ms is the minimum for this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ca3ee5y8/4/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder look's like firefox is trying to optimize stuff even further and if there was no paint and reflow before your timer callback got evaluated, you are out of luck. That's why it's good to know how to trigger it synchronously. You can do it in the beginning of the callback if you wish to.

Comment: @Frizi excellent explanation. I'm curious, is there some official documentation that goes into this with some more depth? Something on MDN perhaps?

Comment: The MDN page 'Web animations on large screens' mentions this as well as the workaround as a [disadvantage of CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS_for_TV/Web_animations_on_large_screen#Disadvantages_of_using_CSS_transitions). Other than that I did not find a designated page or note on this on MDN.

Comment: It looks like calling `getComputedStyle` on the element, even when assigning it to a variable, is optimized away by the JIT. (Only when I log it to the console does  the reflow seem to occur. Accessing `offsetWidth` (even without use) seems to work though.

Comment: Many thanks for trick of accessing `offsetWidth`! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: `setTimeout(0)` doesn't work. `getComputedStyle()` doesn't work. `offsetWidth` works.

Answer (score 36):

Using `jQuery` try this ([An Example Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/q34kA/2/)):

```
var $a = $('<div>')
.addClass('box a')
.appendTo('#wrapper');
$a.css('opacity'); // added
$a.addClass('in');
```

Using Vanilla javaScript try this:

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.className = 'box e';
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(e);
window.getComputedStyle(e).opacity; // added
e.className += ' in';
```

Brief idea:

> The [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) flushes all pending style changes and
>   forces the layout engine to compute the element's current state, hence
>   [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) works similar way.

About `css()`from `jQuery` site:

> The .css() method is a convenient way to get a style property from the
>   first matched element, especially in light of the different ways
>   browsers access most of those properties (the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)()
>   method in standards-based browsers versus the [currentStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and
>   runtimeStyle properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms
>   browsers use for certain properties.

You may use `getComputedStyle()/css()` instead of `setTimeout`. Also you may read [this article](http://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/) for some details information and examples.

Comment: Another great answer, +1

Comment: I noticed that .css('opacity') was not flushing the style changes in IE11 with jquery version 2.2. Instead .offset() did the trick in IE11

Answer (score 13):

Please use the below code, use "focus()"

## Jquery

```
var $a = $('<div>')
    .addClass('box a')
    .appendTo('#wrapper');
$a.focus(); // focus Added
$a.addClass('in');
```

## Javascript

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.className = 'box e';
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(e).focus(); // focus Added
e.className += ' in';
```

Comment: The question says this much. I want to understand _why_.

Comment: This is the absolute best way. Just adding a ".focus()" after the appendChild is a nice and elegant solution.

Comment: @joews the problem is that this is copy pasted from the solution above - that's why it doesn't say anything

Answer (score 9):

I prefer requestAnimationFrame + setTimeout (see [this post](https://nolanlawson.com/2018/09/25/accurately-measuring-layout-on-the-web/)).

```
const child = document.createElement("div");
child.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
child.style.width = "100px";
child.style.height = "100px";
child.style.transition = "1s";

parent.appendChild(child);

requestAnimationFrame(() =>
  setTimeout(() => {
    child.style.width = "200px";
  })
);
```

Try it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j25xj68l09).

Comment: Why do you like that better than simply adding ".focus()" at the end of your appendChild line? parent.appendChild(child).focus();

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this was the only trick that worked consistently for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

@Frizi's solution works, but at times I've found that `getComputedStyle` has not worked when I change certain properties on an element. If that doesn't work, you can try `getBoundingClientRect()` as follows, which I've found to be bulletproof:

Let's assume we have an element `el`, on which we want to transition `opacity`, but `el` is `display:none; opacity: 0`:

```
el.style.display = 'block';
el.style.transition = 'opacity .5s linear';

// reflow
el.getBoundingClientRect();

// it transitions!
el.style.opacity = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

### Anything fundamentally wrong with using keyframes for "animate on create"?

(if you strictly don't want those animations on the initial nodes, add another class `.initial` inhibitin animation)

```js
function addNode() {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hello");
  node.appendChild(textnode);

  document.getElementById("here").appendChild(node);  
}

setTimeout( addNode, 500);
setTimeout( addNode, 1000);
```

```css
body, html { background: #444; display: flex; min-height: 100vh; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
button { font-size: 4em; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 60px;}

div {
  width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 12px solid white; border-radius: 20px; margin: 10px;
  background: gray;
  animation: bouncy .5s linear forwards;
}

/* suppres for initial elements */
div.initial {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes bouncy {
  0% { transform: scale(.1); opacity: 0 }  
  80% { transform: scale(1.15); opacity: 1 }  
  90% { transform: scale(.9); }  
  100% { transform: scale(1); }  
}
```

```html
<section id="here">
  <div class="target initial"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: It has some flaws though. For instance, when you overwrite `animation` property in `div:hover`, then the initial animation will fire again after the element is "unhovered", which might be not desirable.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to force an immediate repaint or style calculation, I tried using `requestAnimationFrame()` to allow the browser to paint on its next available frame.

In Chrome + Firefox, the browser optimizes rendering too much so this still doesn't help (works in Safari).

I settled on manually forcing a delay with `setTimeout()` then using `requestAnimationFrame()` to responsibly let the browser paint. If the append hasn't painted before the timeout ends the animation might be ignored, but it seems to work reliably.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        // trigger the animation
    });
}, 20);
```

I chose 20ms because it's larger than 1 frame at 60fps (16.7ms) and some browsers won't register timeouts <5ms.

Fingers crossed that should force the animation start into the next frame and then start it responsibly when the browser is ready to paint again.

Comment: Yes. None of the other solutions worked for me. The only way i found is to setTimeout with minimum timeout of 15ms

Comment: Would it be more reliable to do two nested `requestAnimationFrame` calls? 

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout()` works only due to **race conditions**, [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) should be used instead. But the `offsetWidth` trick works the best out of all options.

Here is an example situation. We have a series of boxes that each need to be animated downward in sequence. To get everything to work we **need to get an animation frame twice per element**, here I put once before the animation and once after, but it also seems to work if you just put them one after another.

#### Using `requestAnimationFrame` twice works:

Works regardless of how exactly the 2 `getFrame()`s and single set-class-name step are ordered.

```js
const delay = (d) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, d));
const getFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => window.requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

async function run() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const box = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(box);

    // BEFORE
    await getFrame();
    //await delay(1);

    box.className = 'move';
    
    // AFTER
    await getFrame();
    //await delay(1);
  }
}

run();
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.move {
  transform: translate(0px, 100px);
}
```

#### Using `setTimeout` twice fails:

Since this is race condition-based, exact results will vary a lot depending on your browser and computer. Increasing the `setTimeout` delay helps the animation win the race more often, but guarantees nothing.

With Firefox on my Surfacebook 1, and with a delay of 2ms / el, I see about 50% of the boxes failing. With a delay of 20ms / el I see about 10% of the boxes failing.

```js
const delay = (d) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, d));
const getFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => window.requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

async function run() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const box = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(box);

    // BEFORE
    //await getFrame();
    await delay(1);

    box.className = 'move';
    
    // AFTER
    //await getFrame();
    await delay(1);
  }
}

run();
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.move {
  transform: translate(0px, 100px);
}
```

#### Using `requestAnimationFrame` once and `setTimeout` usually works:

This is [Brendan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617982/2398020) (`setTimeout` first) or [pomber's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228987/2398020) (`requestAnimationFrame` first).

```py
# works:
getFrame()
delay(0)
ANIMATE

# works:
delay(0)
getFrame()
ANIMATE

# works:
delay(0)
ANIMATE
getFrame()

# fails:
getFrame()
ANIMATE
delay(0)
```

The once case where it doesn't work (for me) is when getting a frame, then animating, then delaying. I do not have an explanation why.

```js
const delay = (d) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, d));
const getFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => window.requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

async function run() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const box = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(box);

    // BEFORE
    await getFrame();
    await delay(1);

    box.className = 'move';
    
    // AFTER
    //await getFrame();
    //await delay(1);
  }
}

run();
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.move {
  transform: translate(0px, 100px);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout() works only due to race conditions`: I think that's not true, `setTimeout()` works because it pushes the function you pass it into the callback queue, and then the even loop waits until the current call stack is emptied, and it then pushes the function into the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: the technique used in the original answer, below the horizontal rule, does not work 100% of the time, as noted in the comments by [mindplay.dk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148403/trigger-css-transition-on-appended-element#comment112133736_48118842).**

Currently, if using `requestAnimationFrame()`, [pomber's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228987/7700187) is probably the best, as can be seen in the [article linked to](https://nolanlawson.com/2018/09/25/accurately-measuring-layout-on-the-web/) in pomber's answer. The article has been updated since pomber answered, and it now mentions [requestPostAnimationFrame()](https://github.com/WICG/request-post-animation-frame/blob/master/explainer.md), available behind the Chrome flag [--enable-experimental-web-platform-features](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/public_webgl/2005/msg00016.php) now.

When `requestPostAnimationFrame()` reaches a stable state in all major browsers, this will presumably work reliably:

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);

requestPostAnimationFrame(() => div.className = "fade");
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

For the time being, however, there is a polyfill called [AfterFrame](https://github.com/andrewiggins/afterframe), which is also referenced in the aforementioned article. Example:

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);

window.afterFrame(() => div.className = "fade");
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/afterframe/dist/afterframe.umd.js"></script>
```

---

Original answer:

Unlike [Brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617982/7700187), I found that [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) worked in Chrome 63, Firefox 57, IE11 and Edge.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);

requestAnimationFrame(function () {
  div.className = "fade";
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

Comment: Using `requestAnimationFrame()` works for me; I had the same issue from 4 years ago where I forced redraw using `$element.hide().show().addClass("visible")` to get my animation to work; this approach is much better!

Comment: For me, this appears to work randomly... I'm inserting some HTML at page load, so there's a lot going in the browser at this time (loading/parsing more scripts, css, images, etc.) and every third or fourth refresh, the animation doesn't happen. I settled on two nested `requestAnimationFrame` calls for now, which does the job.

Comment: @mindplay.dk you're right. I managed to get the snippet to fail a few times (in Firefox, but not Chrome), so I've updated the answer. I'd be interested to know if either of the things I've added work reliably in your case (even if not in production)?

Comment: @DanL the approach in the original answer doesn't  work 100% of the time, so you may want to reevaluate the options, if you're still using this.