# SVG transition is not working

Tags: javascript, svg

As long as there is no z-index for SVG, I made my rectangles change z-position with DOM manipulations. However, I have a new problem. For some reason transition stops to work. I suspect it is because of DOM reordering, but I HAVE TO use it like that.

```js
function redZ() {
  document.getElementById('svgField').appendChild(document.getElementById('redRect'));
  document.getElementById('redRect').style.transition = "2s linear";
  document.getElementById('redRect').style.fill = "black";
}

function blueZ() {
  document.getElementById('svgField').appendChild(document.getElementById('blueRect'));
  document.getElementById('blueRect').style.transition = "2s linear";
  document.getElementById('blueRect').style.fill = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<svg width="180" height="150" id="svgField">
   <rect onclick="redZ()" id="redRect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
   <rect onclick="blueZ()" id="blueRect" x="60" y="40" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Depending on the overall structure of your actual SVG, you have the option of splitting the elements in your SVG into separate `<svg>` elements, and apply `z-index` on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the redrawing caused by the DOM manipulation. The following is not very elegant, but setting a timeout of a low milliseconds value (in some circumstances you might meed a slightly higher value of 50/100ms) can often solve redrawing-related issues as a last resort.

In addition, you should avoid changing the transition value on every click, that's simply not needed.

```js
document.getElementById('redRect').style.transition = "2s linear";
document.getElementById('blueRect').style.transition = "2s linear";

function redZ() {
  document.getElementById('svgField').appendChild(document.getElementById('redRect'));
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('redRect').style.fill = "black";
  }, 10);
}

function blueZ() {
  document.getElementById('svgField').appendChild(document.getElementById('blueRect'));
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('blueRect').style.fill = "yellow";
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<svg width="180" height="150" id="svgField">
   <rect onclick="redZ()" id="redRect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
   <rect onclick="blueZ()" id="blueRect" x="60" y="40" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: _"This seems to be a problem with the redrawing caused by the DOM manipulation."_ - more exactly, it is a problem with when "control" is handed back over to the rendering engine. _All_ of the DOM and style manipulation is performed as one uninterrupted task. The element is appended to the specified DOM position, and the CSS transition and fill properties are set. Only then is this handed over to the rendering engine, which (for the original `redZ` function example) looks at it and goes, ok, so you have given me an element with a black fill color, [...]

Comment: [...] and I am supposed to transition everything when some property changes. Got it! Lemme check ... nope, fill color still back, everything else still the same - I think we're done here? The slight timeout (more "modern" approaches usually use `requestAnimationFrame`) fixes this, because it hands control over to rendering in between the two steps, too, appending of the element to the DOM, and the change of fill color - so when the RE looks at it again after the fill color change, it now has the change to recognize that change in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for going into more detail on this than I could. Just a quick note, requestAnimationFrame was what I tried first, but it seems that wasn't enough delay in order to handle this.

Comment: You're right, apparently browsers optimize _against_ that with rAF (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617982/1427878), so setTimeout is the safer approach here. Good point.

Comment: As mentioned in other answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/24148403/1427878, sometimes explicitly doing something in JS in between that forces it to "ask" the rendering engine for stuff explicitly (like an element's offsetWidth, bounding client rectangle, etc.) can also make this work.

Comment: Could the downvoter be bothered to explain their reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the active `rect` above the other `rect` in the DOM order, move the *other* `rect` below the *active* `rect`. This allows the transitions to work as expected.

In other words, when the `redRect` is clicked, instead of moving the `redRect` to the bottom of the DOM order (so it's visually on top), move the `blueRect` to the top of the DOM order (so it's visually on bottom). With:

`document.getElementById('svgField').prepend(document.getElementById('blueRect'));`

Like this:

```js
function redZ() {
  document.getElementById('svgField').prepend(document.getElementById('blueRect'));
  document.getElementById('redRect').style.transition = "2s linear";
  document.getElementById('redRect').style.fill = "black";
}

function blueZ() {
  document.getElementById('svgField').prepend(document.getElementById('redRect'));
  document.getElementById('blueRect').style.transition = "2s linear";
  document.getElementById('blueRect').style.fill = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<svg width="180" height="150" id="svgField">
   <rect onclick="redZ()" id="redRect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
   <rect onclick="blueZ()" id="blueRect" x="60" y="40" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
   
</svg>
```