# How to appendChild with Animation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I cant use Jquery (just javascript). 
I have a simple array of images that I find a random index values and appendChild(MyRandomImages) (3 images all at once) to the page. I need it to be appended with a transition animation ease-in 0.5s, ease-in 1s, ease-in 1.5s.

```
images = ["image/1.png",
          "image/2.png",
          "image/3.png",
          "image/4.png",
          "image/5.png",
          "image/6.png"];

var img = document.createElement("img");
var img1 = document.createElement("img");
var img2 = document.createElement("img");  

var randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
var randomVal1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
var randomVal2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);

img.src = images[randomVal];
img1.src = images[randomVal1];
img2.src = images[randomVal2];


var result = document.getElementsByClassName("result");
result[0].appendChild(img);
result[1].appendChild(img1);
result[2].appendChild(img2);
```

So result[0].appendChild(img) needs somehow to have preventDefault() and be animated into the scene, I tried invoking css3 animation by adding a new class that animates it. So if class:

```
.result {
width:0;
height:0;}
```

And I did
el.classList.add("animate"); where el is result class:

```
.animate{
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

but it didnt work. and I had the logical problem of how applying three classes to each one since I need them to be appended at different times (0.5, 1, 1.5s).

I would very much like to somehow invoke a css3 animation to do this and use no Jquery.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger CSS transition on appended element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148403/trigger-css-transition-on-appended-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append images sequentially you can do:

- use JS's `.forEach(element, index)` that:
- creates a random image
- appends the image to DOM
- use `setTimeout(()=> {/*job*/}, time * index )` where `time*index` will result in N timeouts like: `0, 500, 1500 ....` having `time` set to `500`*ms* and the *job* is to **add your `.animate` class**.

```js
const images = [
  "//placehold.it/300x300/0bf",
  "//placehold.it/300x300/f0b",
  "//placehold.it/300x300/bf0",
  "//placehold.it/300x300/0fb",
  "//placehold.it/300x300/b0f",
  "//placehold.it/300x300/fb0",
];

const createImg = (el, i) => {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = images[~~(Math.random() * images.length)];
  el.appendChild(img);
  setTimeout(()=> img.classList.add("animate"), i*500);
}


document.querySelectorAll(".result").forEach(createImg);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.result img{
  max-width: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.result img.animate{
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that works just the way I needed. Not to mentioned you removed many repetition by using forEach().

Comment: @AliR :) glad it helped. Happy coding

Comment: are the ~~ to ensure it always return a positive index number? isnt the length of array always positive?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append your images with a specified delay you could use setTimeout like this:

```
// append
setTimeout(function(){
  // append
  setTimeout(function(){
    // append
  }, 500)
}, 500)
```

This will append a image and will wait 500ms till the next will be appended. Then you still use the same duration time for your transition.

Regarding your animation issue: 
Your image should have the transition property before you change the property to be animated.
So your img style has the transition property by default. After you appended your element in javascript you give it a class (in your case with the new property values of the height and width) with the different values in it, e.g.:

```
.result{
  // with "all" you apply a transition to all css properties
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.visible{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

So just then add the visible class to the image after you applied it