# Map works in Chrome but does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

When creating an interactive map I need to enlarge the selected object when I hover over.
CSS rules execute this part of the task.

Next, I needed the enlarged object to always be higher than the rest of the map objects.
Javascript does this part of the task.

Everything works fine in the Chrome browser.
Hovering and zooming with CSS rules does not work in Firefox and the selected object does not pop up.

I would be very grateful for any idea to solve this problem.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path.state1').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
  });
});
```

```css
.state1 {
fill:white;
stroke:dodgerblue;
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition:  1s;
}

:hover.state1 {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);
 
 }
```

```html
<body>
   <section id="map">

    <svg version="1.1"
       id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   <g>
   <title>"ID" - IDAHO
   State capital city - Boise
   Population - 228,790
   </title>
      <path id="ID"  class="state1" d="
        M615.5-107.5l8.8-35.2l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8
        l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.5-4.4l13.6-63.3l13.5,2.5l-4.4,21.4l3.6,7.5l-1.6,4.7l2,4.6l3.1,1.3l3.8,9.6l3.5,4.4l0.5,1.1l3.3,1.1
        l0.4,2.1l-7,17.4l-0.2,2.6l2.6,3.3l0.9,0l4.9-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.3,5.4l2.7,12.6l3.9,3.2l1.7,2.2l-0.7,4.1l1.1,2.8l1.1,1.1
        l2.5-2.4l2.8,0l2.9,1.3l2.8-0.7l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.5-3l2.9-0.8l1.3,1.5l0.4,2.9l1.4,1.2l-8.4,53.6
        C710.4-89.3,622.5-106,615.5-107.5z"/> 
  </g>
  <g>    
 <title>   "UT" - Utah
   State capital city - Salt Lake City
   Population
   City 186,440
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 200,591
   </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="state1" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
      <g>    
 <title>   "AZ" - Arizona
   State capital city - Phoenix
   Population
   City 1,445,632
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 1,660,272
   </title>
   <path id="AZ" class="state1" d="
        M611.9,98.6l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25,2.7l17.3-119.1l-83.7-11.9l-3.1,16.4l-1.6,0
        l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1H628l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8
        l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l0.1,0.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7
        l-1.5,2.2L611.9,98.6z"/>
</g>  
<g>    
 <title>   "NV" - Nevada
   State capital city - Carson City
   Population
   City 55,274
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 55,414
   </title>
      <path id="NV" class="state1" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>  
<g>    
 <title>   "OR" - Oregon
   State capital city - Salem
   Population
   City 154,637
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 173,442
   </title>
      <path id="OR" class="state1" d="
        M615.7-108.5l8.9-34.8l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9
        l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.8-4.6l-12.7-3.6l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7l-4.7-0.2l-1.7-1.4
        l-5.3-2.1l-0.8,0.1l-4.3-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5
        l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l0.4,12.1L615.7-108.5z"/>
</g>     
  <g>
   <title>   "WA" - Washington Territory
   State capital city - Olympia
   Population
   City 46,478
   Estimate (2018) 52,555
   </title>
      <path id="WA" class="state1"  d="
        M569.1-276.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.2l-13.6,63.6l-12.4-3.5l-15.5-3.6l-15.2,0l-0.5-1.3l-5.6,2.2l-4.6-0.7
        l-2.1-1.6L579-200l-4.7-0.1l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2.1l-0.7,0.1l-4.4-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.3-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.8-0.9l0.1-7.7l-2.3-3.8l-4.1-0.6
        l-0.7-2.5l-2.3-0.5l-3.6,1.2l-2.3-3.2l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2
        l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5
        l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5v-2.3l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.9l0.3-0.8
        L569.1-276.4z M559.6-270.4l2-0.2l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2
        s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6l-1.5-2.3L559.6-270.4z"/>
  </g> 
  <g>
   <title>   "CA" - California
   State capital city - Sacramento
   Population
   City 466,488
   Estimate (2018) 508,529
   </title>
      <path id="CA" class="state1" d="
        M611.7,98.2l3.9-0.5l1.5-2l0.5-2.9l-3.6-0.6l-0.5-0.7l0.5-2l-0.2-0.6l1.9-0.6l3-2.8l0.6-5l1.4-3.4l1.9-2.2l3.5-1.6l1.7-1.6l0.1-2.1
        l-1-0.6l-1-1.1l-1.2-5.8l-2.7-4.8l0.6-3.5l-2.4-1L551.3-51.5l18.9-67.6l-67.1-15.7l-1.5,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1
        l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5l2.3,4.9l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2
        l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9
        l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1
        h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.9l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2l3.2-1.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2
        l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L611.7,98.2z M523.6,54.5l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L523.6,54.5z
         M525.5,54.5l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L525.5,54.5z M546.2,74.3l1.8,2.3l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8
        l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V74.3z M544.7,82.9l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9s0-2.2,0-2.2L544.7,82.9z"/>
  </g>
    </svg>

  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? "Does not work" is pretty broad

Comment: @Nico Haase The debugger showed that movements in the DOM occur, but the elements after that do not respond to the hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would remove your JavaScript logic and your code will work on Chrome and Firefox, but overlap of paths will be an issue.

To control 'z-index' of the path you are appending current path to the svg, but hover event is not applied from CSS in Firefox. In order to fix this issue you need to rename `:hover` to `.scaled`, and then from javascript toggle that class.

You can read about why I added `setTimeout` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24195559/7132835)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path.state1').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
 const paths = [...document.querySelectorAll('path.state1')]
 setTimeout(()=> {
 paths[paths.length - 1].classList.add('scaled');    
 },20)
 
  });
});


document.querySelectorAll('path.state1').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
 path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
 const paths = [...document.querySelectorAll('path.state1')]
 
    setTimeout(()=> {
paths[paths.length - 1].classList.remove('scaled');       
 },20)
  });
});
```

```css
.state1 {
fill: white;
stroke:dodgerblue;
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition:  1s;
}

.state1.scaled {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);
 }
```

```html
<section id="map">

    <svg version="1.1"
       id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   <g>
   <title>"ID" - IDAHO
   State capital city - Boise
   Population - 228,790
   </title>
      <path id="ID"  class="state1" d="
        M615.5-107.5l8.8-35.2l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8
        l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.5-4.4l13.6-63.3l13.5,2.5l-4.4,21.4l3.6,7.5l-1.6,4.7l2,4.6l3.1,1.3l3.8,9.6l3.5,4.4l0.5,1.1l3.3,1.1
        l0.4,2.1l-7,17.4l-0.2,2.6l2.6,3.3l0.9,0l4.9-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.3,5.4l2.7,12.6l3.9,3.2l1.7,2.2l-0.7,4.1l1.1,2.8l1.1,1.1
        l2.5-2.4l2.8,0l2.9,1.3l2.8-0.7l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.5-3l2.9-0.8l1.3,1.5l0.4,2.9l1.4,1.2l-8.4,53.6
        C710.4-89.3,622.5-106,615.5-107.5z"/> 
  </g>
  <g>    
 <title>   "UT" - Utah
   State capital city - Salt Lake City
   Population
   City 186,440
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 200,591
   </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="state1" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
      <g>    
 <title>   "AZ" - Arizona
   State capital city - Phoenix
   Population
   City 1,445,632
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 1,660,272
   </title>
   <path id="AZ" class="state1" d="
        M611.9,98.6l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25,2.7l17.3-119.1l-83.7-11.9l-3.1,16.4l-1.6,0
        l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1H628l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8
        l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l0.1,0.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7
        l-1.5,2.2L611.9,98.6z"/>
</g>  
<g>    
 <title>   "NV" - Nevada
   State capital city - Carson City
   Population
   City 55,274
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 55,414
   </title>
      <path id="NV" class="state1" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>  
<g>    
 <title>   "OR" - Oregon
   State capital city - Salem
   Population
   City 154,637
   Estimate Estimate (2018) 173,442
   </title>
      <path id="OR" class="state1" d="
        M615.7-108.5l8.9-34.8l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9
        l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.8-4.6l-12.7-3.6l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7l-4.7-0.2l-1.7-1.4
        l-5.3-2.1l-0.8,0.1l-4.3-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5
        l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l0.4,12.1L615.7-108.5z"/>
</g>     
  <g>
   <title>   "WA" - Washington Territory
   State capital city - Olympia
   Population
   City 46,478
   Estimate (2018) 52,555
   </title>
      <path id="WA" class="state1"  d="
        M569.1-276.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.2l-13.6,63.6l-12.4-3.5l-15.5-3.6l-15.2,0l-0.5-1.3l-5.6,2.2l-4.6-0.7
        l-2.1-1.6L579-200l-4.7-0.1l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2.1l-0.7,0.1l-4.4-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.3-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.8-0.9l0.1-7.7l-2.3-3.8l-4.1-0.6
        l-0.7-2.5l-2.3-0.5l-3.6,1.2l-2.3-3.2l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2
        l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5
        l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5v-2.3l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.9l0.3-0.8
        L569.1-276.4z M559.6-270.4l2-0.2l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2
        s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6l-1.5-2.3L559.6-270.4z"/>
  </g> 
  <g>
   <title>   "CA" - California
   State capital city - Sacramento
   Population
   City 466,488
   Estimate (2018) 508,529
   </title>
      <path id="CA" class="state1" d="
        M611.7,98.2l3.9-0.5l1.5-2l0.5-2.9l-3.6-0.6l-0.5-0.7l0.5-2l-0.2-0.6l1.9-0.6l3-2.8l0.6-5l1.4-3.4l1.9-2.2l3.5-1.6l1.7-1.6l0.1-2.1
        l-1-0.6l-1-1.1l-1.2-5.8l-2.7-4.8l0.6-3.5l-2.4-1L551.3-51.5l18.9-67.6l-67.1-15.7l-1.5,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1
        l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5l2.3,4.9l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2
        l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9
        l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1
        h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.9l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2l3.2-1.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2
        l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L611.7,98.2z M523.6,54.5l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L523.6,54.5z
         M525.5,54.5l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L525.5,54.5z M546.2,74.3l1.8,2.3l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8
        l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V74.3z M544.7,82.9l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9s0-2.2,0-2.2L544.7,82.9z"/>
  </g>
    </svg>

  </section>
```

Comment: In your decision - delete JS - the selected object does not pop up over other objects. Try replacing fill: transparent; with another color such as fill: white and you will see that the selected object does not pop up. Only JS can solve this problem by adding the selected object to the DOM last I put a plus for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, key feature - is not move the alredy last node:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path.state').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if (path.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('g:last-child') !== path.parentNode)
      path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
  });
});
```

```html
<style>
  .state {
    fill: white;
    stroke: dodgerblue;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  :hover.state {
    fill: dodgerblue;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    filter:url(#dropshadow);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <section id="map">

    <svg version="1.1" id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>    
      <g>
   <title>"ID" - IDAHO
State capital city - Boise
Population - 228,790
   </title>
      <path id="ID"  class="state" d="
        M615.5-107.5l8.8-35.2l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8
        l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.5-4.4l13.6-63.3l13.5,2.5l-4.4,21.4l3.6,7.5l-1.6,4.7l2,4.6l3.1,1.3l3.8,9.6l3.5,4.4l0.5,1.1l3.3,1.1
        l0.4,2.1l-7,17.4l-0.2,2.6l2.6,3.3l0.9,0l4.9-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.3,5.4l2.7,12.6l3.9,3.2l1.7,2.2l-0.7,4.1l1.1,2.8l1.1,1.1
        l2.5-2.4l2.8,0l2.9,1.3l2.8-0.7l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.5-3l2.9-0.8l1.3,1.5l0.4,2.9l1.4,1.2l-8.4,53.6
        C710.4-89.3,622.5-106,615.5-107.5z"/> 
  </g>
  <g>    
 <title>"UT" - Utah
State capital city - Salt Lake City
Population
City 186,440
Estimate Estimate (2018) 200,591
   </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="state" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
      <g>    
 <title>"AZ" - Arizona
State capital city - Phoenix
Population
City 1,445,632
Estimate Estimate (2018) 1,660,272
   </title>
   <path id="AZ" class="state" d="
        M611.9,98.6l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25,2.7l17.3-119.1l-83.7-11.9l-3.1,16.4l-1.6,0
        l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1H628l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8
        l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l0.1,0.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7
        l-1.5,2.2L611.9,98.6z"/>
</g>  
<g>    
 <title>"NV" - Nevada
State capital city - Carson City
Population
City 55,274
Estimate Estimate (2018) 55,414
   </title>
      <path id="NV" class="state" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>  
<g>    
 <title>"OR" - Oregon
State capital city - Salem
Population
City 154,637
Estimate Estimate (2018) 173,442
   </title>
      <path id="OR" class="state" d="
        M615.7-108.5l8.9-34.8l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9
        l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.8-4.6l-12.7-3.6l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7l-4.7-0.2l-1.7-1.4
        l-5.3-2.1l-0.8,0.1l-4.3-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5
        l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l0.4,12.1L615.7-108.5z"/>
</g>     
  <g>
   <title>"WA" - Washington Territory
State capital city - Olympia
Population
City 46,478
Estimate (2018) 52,555
   </title>
      <path id="WA" class="state" class="state" d="
        M569.1-276.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.2l-13.6,63.6l-12.4-3.5l-15.5-3.6l-15.2,0l-0.5-1.3l-5.6,2.2l-4.6-0.7
        l-2.1-1.6L579-200l-4.7-0.1l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2.1l-0.7,0.1l-4.4-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.3-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.8-0.9l0.1-7.7l-2.3-3.8l-4.1-0.6
        l-0.7-2.5l-2.3-0.5l-3.6,1.2l-2.3-3.2l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2
        l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5
        l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5v-2.3l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.9l0.3-0.8
        L569.1-276.4z M559.6-270.4l2-0.2l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2
        s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6l-1.5-2.3L559.6-270.4z"/>
  </g> 
  <g>
   <title>"CA" - California
State capital city - Sacramento
Population
City 466,488
Estimate (2018) 508,529
   </title>
      <path id="CA" class="state" d="
        M611.7,98.2l3.9-0.5l1.5-2l0.5-2.9l-3.6-0.6l-0.5-0.7l0.5-2l-0.2-0.6l1.9-0.6l3-2.8l0.6-5l1.4-3.4l1.9-2.2l3.5-1.6l1.7-1.6l0.1-2.1
        l-1-0.6l-1-1.1l-1.2-5.8l-2.7-4.8l0.6-3.5l-2.4-1L551.3-51.5l18.9-67.6l-67.1-15.7l-1.5,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1
        l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5l2.3,4.9l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2
        l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9
        l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1
        h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.9l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2l3.2-1.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2
        l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L611.7,98.2z M523.6,54.5l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L523.6,54.5z
         M525.5,54.5l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L525.5,54.5z M546.2,74.3l1.8,2.3l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8
        l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V74.3z M544.7,82.9l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9s0-2.2,0-2.2L544.7,82.9z"/>
  </g>
    </svg>

  </section>
</body>
```