# How to add an animation effect when a component is displayed in re-frame?

Tags: css, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have a component which is wrapped in an if like so:

```
(if @(subscribe [:some-condition])
    [:div.show-me "Show me"]
)
```

And I want to apply an animation to the show-me div as soon as it is displayed, i.e., when the condition is true. 
Now, I know how to apply transitions in css using selectors like :hover, and :active, for example:

```
.show-me {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.show-me:hover {
    transform: scale (1.1em);
}
```

Will scale the div when hovered over.

But how to scale, for example, a div as soon as it is shown?

Comment: This isn't really specific to Reagent, and you'd probably get better results if you posted a React version of this question and applied the answers, but the short answer is you are trying to [Animate an element on append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148403/trigger-css-transition-on-appended-element)